# How to remove an item selected from a listbox from a list containing multiple objects?

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I want a user to be able to select an item from the listbox then press the delete button so that item is deleted from the listbox as well as the allFlights list. How could I change my code so it also deletes the item from the allFlights list?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Flight> allFlights;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        allFlights = new List<Flight>();

        Flight flight1 = new Flight("BA431", "Newcastle", "13:00");
        Flight flight2 = new Flight("KL126", "Manchester", "16:00");
        Flight flight3 = new Flight("CD230", "London", "14:00");
        allFlights.Add(flight1);
        allFlights.Add(flight2);
        allFlights.Add(flight3);
        allFlights.Sort();

        DisplayArrivals();
    }

    public void DisplayArrivals()
    {
        foreach (Flight f in allFlights)
        {
            lstArrivals.Items.Add(f.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnDeleteF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = lstArrivals.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            lstArrivals.Items.RemoveAt(lstArrivals.SelectedIndices[i]);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are removing the Flights but not removing from the lstArrivals.Items.  So you need a 2nd for loop in the Delete Method similar to the existing for loop that removes from the lstArrivals.Items.

Comment: I would remove items from `allFlights` then refresh `lstArrivals.Items` (call `lstArrivals.Items.Clear()` then `DisplayArrivals()`)

Comment: I'm unsure how to write that so it deletes what's selected from the list box

Comment: For each selected `item` you should remove the `flight` where `flight.ToString() == item` (this assumes that your `ToString()` function returns something different for each flight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for (int i = lstArrivals.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    allFlights.Remove(lstArrivals.Items[lstArrivals.SelectedIndices[i]]);
    lstArrivals.Items.RemoveAt(lstArrivals.SelectedIndices[i]);
}
```

Comment: I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'FlightArrivals.Flight'" on the lstArrivals.SelectedIndicies[i] bit

Comment: I changed the allFlights.Remove to allFlights.RemoveAt and it works so ty :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `DisplayArrivals()` method, instead of adding `f.ToString()` to your ListBox, add the `Flight` instance itself, as in `lstArrivals.Items.Add(f)`:

```
public void DisplayArrivals()
{
    foreach (Flight f in allFlights)
    {
        lstArrivals.Items.Add(f); // <-- add the Flight instance itself
    }
}
```

Make sure to override `ToString()` for your `Flight` class to control how it displays in the ListBox.

Then you can cast the selected item back to a Flight instance and use that reference to remove it from your list:

```
private void btnDeleteF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = lstArrivals.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Flight f = lstArrivals.Items[lstArrivals.SelectedIndices[i]] as Flight;
        lstArrivals.Items.RemoveAt(lstArrivals.SelectedIndices[i]);
        allFlights.Remove(f);
        // ... possibly do something else with "f" ...
    }
}
```